# graph.facebook.com having very low success rate when measured from Firebase Performance library

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, facebook-events, firebase-performance

[image: fire]

I am using Facebook SDK in my Android Application for sending events of their dashboard. Can anyone tell me what could be the probable reason or is there something which I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well may be you are not doing anything wrong! But this is telling you your app's request to graph.facebook.com is failed in most case(Means there is problem in fetching Ad from F.A.N. may be network problem or in some case).

Comment: But in the app, I am not fetching any Ad.

Comment: What requests are you making?

Comment: I am firing events on Facebook using their SDK for capturing user's behavior. Like user has opened this video or has completed tutorials, etc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android

Comment: I have the same issue, is there any solution on this ? success rate is 85% is not good <90%